# Should we purge the genre tags where they are misapplied?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

The tag wikis for [fantasy-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy-genre) and [science-fiction-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-genre) say that they should be

> Used for questions on the ... genre itself, including its tropes and conventions.

However if you take a look at the tagged questions, they are both used very consistently on story identification questions as stand-ins for the genre in question. About 2/3 of total use across both tags coincides with [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), while only a small portion actually deal with meta-discussion of the genre as the wikis indicate.

This represents at least 165 tag instances which are very likely misapplied. What should we do about them? Purge them from story identification; change the wiki; ban them; something else?

Comment: You have 2k rep, get crackin'

Comment: @Kevin - IIRC, in the past, massive retags were frowned upon (in part because the super-spam both the RSS feeds and "active" questions view)

Comment: @DVK Yes, yes, it was just a joke. Sort of.

Comment: If you do go through and retag, just keep it down to no more than 4, maybe 5 in the top 10 active questions page.

Answer (score 6):

When you see them misapplied, edit the tags on the question to remove them.  Don't do this to the existing questions en masse, as that would obnoxiously flood the front page with the edits. Do a few at a time.

Not sure what you mean by 'purging' them from [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification).

Comment: "purging" as in "do this to the existing questions en masse"

Comment: @Travis I think you mean something different actually. By "purging", I _think_ you mean removing the genre tags from all story-identification questions. Keen is not talking about the quantity of questions, but the _rate_ at which they're removed: don't do 30 edits in a day and flood the front page with those edits; do as many edits as you need but keep it to a small number of questions per day.