# Why don't we have 'science-fiction' and 'fantasy' (or similar) tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

A significant number of [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions are tagged as [science-fiction-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-genre) or [fantasy-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy-genre). However, it is an incorrect use of the tag for specific stories as explained in the tag wiki:

> Used for questions on the science fiction genre itself, including its tropes and conventions. Should **not** be used to categorize questions about specific works of science fiction.

This problem has been [discussed before on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3361/should-we-purge-the-genre-tags-where-they-are-misapplied).

Often these tags are incorrectly used by new users who don't know better and are simply trying to distinguish between works of science fiction vs. fantasy.

I noticed that we do not have tags for [science-fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) and [fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) which could be used to distinguish science fiction vs. fantasy works as these users are trying to do. Should we add these tags and start using them? I would think that most users who attempt to tag their question as science fiction vs. fantasy would correctly choose the new [science-fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) and [fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) tags instead of [science-fiction-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-genre) and [fantasy-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy-genre) since they should better match what the user is already typing to add tags.

I found some very old discussions about adding [science-fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) and [fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) on meta [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306/do-we-need-a-sci-fi-and-a-fantasy-tag) and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/do-we-need-a-sci-fi-tag). However, these discussions appear to predate the creation of the [genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/science-fiction-genre/info) [tags](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/fantasy-genre/info) and they do not address the problem with the genre tags. I agree with the meta discussions that these are very broad tags, but the purpose of these tags would mainly be to *drive users away from incorrectly using the genre tags*.

Should [science-fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) and [fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) be created to address the problem with the genre tags?

EDIT: to avoid tags which are so broad as [science-fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) and [fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy), maybe use something like [science-fiction-story-id](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-story-id)? Or rename the genre tags to something like [science-fiction-tropes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-tropes) to better reflect the purpose of the tag?

Comment: I get your point, but it would be like adding a 'programming' tag on StackOverflow

Answer (score 12):

We don't have these tags because *every* post on the site would have one, the other, or both tags on them.  Pretty much every Stack Exchange site has a similar black list of things that it's pointless to tag with.

People who are asking  questions shouldn't be using these tags, and users who see their misuse should edit them off existing questions (just don't do it en masse, as that'll flood the /questions page).

Comment: Yeah, such broad tags would be a problem. I'm just trying to figure out a way to guide users away from the genre tags. The system isn't working well when tags are so consistently misused and require manual editing. To avoid the problem of overly broad tags maybe use 'science-fiction-story-id' or something instead? Or rename the genre tags to 'science-fiction-tropes' or something?

Comment: An additional reason is that *everybody* would quickly end up having gold tag badges in them, meaning that *everybody* would have instant dupe-hammer powers on *every* question.  Which would be highly undesirable.